# DNS Bind9 automatical $ORIGIN entry

Tags: dns, bind9

I have a zone definition:

```
zone "home" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.home";
        allow-transfer { XX.XXX.XXX.XXX; key "YYYYY";};
        notify yes;
        also-notify { XX.XXX.XXX.XXX;};
        update-policy {
        grant ZZZZZ wildcard *.home A DHCID;
                };
        };
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-transfer { XX.XXX.XXX.XXX; key "YYYYY";};
        notify yes;
        also-notify { XX.XXX.XXX.XXX;};
        update-policy {
        grant ZZZZZ wildcard *.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa PTR;
                };
        };
```

But Bind9 write "$ORIGIN ." in my zone file. That leads into SERVFAIL, if i use "dig" command. The correct value has to be "$ORIGIN home.".
I can correct that manually, but the next update cycle write the false ORIGIN value again.

Any advices?
Thx